# How to disable ctrl + drag in Jira tempo using scriptrunner - script fragments

Tags: jira

for some reason I would like to disable the default Jira Tempo feature that ctrl + drag&drop to another day copies the selected worklog tile. I would like to prevent Jira to perform any action using ctrl and/or drag&drop.

I tried to use the script fragment feature of the jira and this code and to approach the problem by completely disabling the ctrl button:

The ctrl event is recognized but the effect is not blocked.
I know both the approach and the code are problematic. I would be happy, however, if you could give me any hint.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
 if (event.key === "Ctrl") {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   console.log("ctrl is pushed");
   return;
 }
});
```